# "Puesto" as an adjective

Tags: gramática, conjugación

In my spanish homework, we had the following prompt:

> Cuando tengo ____ (poner) ropa elegante, yo...

With the instructions to use the past participle of the given verb then finish the sentence.

My answer was:

> Cuando tengo puesto ropa elegante, trato no ensuciarlo.

Because the prompt was so direct, I knew how to fill in the blank, but I'm hoping somebody can help me wrap my head around the sentence structure.

I can't see how the sentence would work. I understand the direct translation working, but am I incorrect that "puesto" wouldn't be "put on" as in "In the past, I put on clothes" but as an adjective, which wouldn't have a good english equivalent. It seems like puesto is used as a verb here. Can somebody help me understand how this works?

Comment: *Ponerse* is *to put [an item of clothing] on*; once you've put the item on, then you *have it on*: *lo/la tienes puesto/puesta*.  We can use the past participle, *puesto*, as an adjective, and it needs to agree in number and gender with the noun it's modifying, which is the item of clothing.

Answer (score 7):

The correct answer is

> *Cuando tengo **puesta** ropa elegante...*

(the rest is up to you; if you go as you did, note it should be *trato de no ensuciar**la***).

In dictionaries or lists of expressions you will find this as
*tener puesto*, but *puesto* works like an adjective (it's not the invariable passive participle as in the compound tenses, e.g. *haber puesto*).¹ This one has to agree with the direct object, in this case *ropa*, in gender and number. So you would also say

> *Cuando tengo **puesto** un sombrero...* (masc. sing.)
>   *Cuando tengo **puestos** mis zapatos nuevos...* (masc. pl.)
>   *Cuando tengo **puestas** las medias a rayas...* (fem. pl.)

This is not the only expression using *tener* + adjective. It's actually a special usage of *tener* that is similar in meaning (though not identical in grammar) to the perfective tenses with *haber*.² For example, *tener listo* and *tener preparado* mean "to have something ready/prepared, to have readied/prepared something":

> *Ya tengo lista mi mochila.*
>   *Ya tengo preparadas las valijas.*

So *cuando tengo puesta ropa* means more or less the same as *una vez que / después de que me he puesto ropa* (that is, "once I have put such-and-such clothes on..."), but we mostly think of it as a state, "when I'm wearing such-and-such clothes...".³

---

**Notes:**

1. The Spanish passive participle has two main usages: in the compound tenses, with the auxiliary *haber*, where it is invariable; and in the periphrastic passive voice, with the auxiliary *ser*, as well as in related constructions with *estar* and *ponerse*, where it acts like an adjective and has to agree with the referent in gender and number. It's a matter of theory whether e.g. *puesto* in *tener puesto* is an adjective or a variable participle; it doesn't really change anything for the speaker.
2. Constructions with *haber* and *tener* are semantically and historically related. The Latin verb *habere* actually meant "to have" (no etymological relation with English there!), and only later started being replaced by the descendants of the verb *tenere* ("to hold"). So the near-equivalence of *me he puesto ropa* "I have put clothes on" and *tengo puesta ropa* "I'm wearing clothes" has a historical reason.
3. Note that, as with sitting and standing, English prefers a continuous tense ("I'm wearing...") where Spanish uses a perfective or static tense (*"Tengo puesto..."*).

Answer (score 3):

"Tener puesto" is an expression meaning "to wear", and "puesto" agrees with the thing you have on. Here that's "ropa elegante", something feminine, so I believe you should actually write "Cuando tengo puesta ropa elegante...". Some examples here: https://context.reverso.net/translation/spanish-english/tiene+puesta+ropa.